# GRAILS ModalBox pop up not showing

Tags: modal-dialog

I am using Modallbox plugin in Grails.

I have following code in the search template:

And the template is being displayed using div tag in other pages. Now I have included 
modalbox related stuff in the layout page:

Now when I click on modalbox link, the modalbox is not displayed. Instead it goes to new page. But it works for simple page

```
    <g:javascript library="application" />
    <modalbox:modalIncludes />

</head>
<body>
<modalbox:createLink controller="policy" action="show" id="10" title="Show book!" width="500">Book Lorem ipsum</modalbox:createLink>


 </body>
```

Any suggestions....

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

That might be because you have other libraries declared in your  like jquery...